# ss = v[t][w] * po[t][w] IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: indexing

ss = v[t][w] * po[t][w] IndexError: list index out of range

when i try to run my genetic algorithm on population_size=97 is work good
but when i increase it to 100 this error appear.

how can i fix this problem please?

```
type pop_size= 100 #len(data)
print('popsize',pop_size)
bits = 1


personsss = [randint(0, 2, bits*vd).tolist() for k in range(pop_size)]
# print(personsss)
def fitness1(po1,vv):
    sss1 = []
    sums11 = []
    solindx1 = []
    solindx11 = []
    vv = list(vv)
    vv = random.choice(vv)
    pl = 20
    for w in range(vd):
        ss1 = vv[w] * po1[w] 
        sss1.append(ss1)
        if ss1 != 0:
            solindx1.append(w)
    solindx11.append(solindx1)
    sums = sum(sss1) - pl * len(solindx1)   
    sums11.append(sums)
    solindx1 = []
    return sums11, solindx11 


def fitness(po,v):
    sss = []
    sums1 = []
    solindx = []
    solindx1 = []
    pl = 20
    v = list(v)
    for t in range(len(po)):
        for w in range(vd):
            ss = v[t][w] * po[t][w]
            sss.append(ss)
            if ss != 0:
                solindx.append(w)
        solindx1.append(solindx)
        sums = sum(sss) - pl * len(solindx)
        sums1.append(sums)
        solindx = []
    return sums1, solindx1here
```